# Can't figure out has_many/belongs_to RAILS 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, database-migration, has-many, belongs-to

My models are:

```
class CarBrand < ActiveRecord::Base
        has_many :car_models
    end

class CarModel < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :car_brand
end
```

and my migrations are

```
    class CreateCarBrands < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    create_table :car_brands do |t|
      t.string "brand", :limit => 20    
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end

  def down
    drop_table :car_brands
  end
end

    class CreateCarModels < ActiveRecord::Migration
   def up
    create_table :car_models do |t|
      t.references :car_brand
      t.string "model", :limit => 20      
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
    add_index :car_models, :car_brand_id
  end
  def down 
    drop_table :car_models
  end
end
```

and i want to get car models according to specific car brand, in database i have both records, but when i type in console it gives error

```
somecar = CarBrand.where(:brand => 'Toyota')
somecar.car_models
```

so it doesn't returns me models of toyota, but i have them in database!!!

Comment: What does it return? `somecar` in your example is an array

Comment: I'm surprised nobody mentioned `Model.find_by` that fetches a first matching record. It's not worth a separate answer, but still good to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like that:-

```
somecar = CarBrand.where(:brand => 'Toyota')
somecar.first.car_models
```

As `CarBrand.where(:brand => 'Toyota')` returns an array.

OR

Try like that:-

```
somecar = CarBrand.find_by brand: 'Toyota'
somecar.car_models
```

`CarBrand.find_by brand: 'Toyota'` will fetch first matching record.

Comment: *array* -- uhm, [not really](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html), but the answer is still more or less correct.

Comment: OK, it asks to wait a bit

Answer (score 1):

`somecar = CarBrand.where(:brand => 'Toyota')` returns an active record relation `#<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<.....` the main point is that it is a collection. You have to iterate over each item in the collection.

`some_cars = CarBrand.where(:brand => 'Toyota') 
    some_cars.each do |car| puts car.car_model end`

or on the first item `some_cars.first.car_model`

Notice I changed some_car to some_cars, the name of the variable does matter but it is easier to see that it is a collection. Notice I called `.car_model` (and NOT `car_models`) on each item, that really is important.